# As both fs.promises.readFile() and fs.promises.access() need to be catched if a file doesn't exist, is there any reason to use fs.promises.access()?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to read a file content, using `fs.promises.readFile()`.

Obviously I want to be sure the file exists, and found that I can use `fs.promises.access()` to check this.

However, as I need to catch `fs.promises.access()` if the file doesn't exist, is there any reason to use it for this use case or should I just go with `fs.promises.readFile()` and catch it too ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason to use `access` to see if the file exists if you're going to use `readFile`; just handle the error from `readFile`. And in fact, there are reasons *not* to use `access` first.

They mention this in [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_access_path_mode):

> Using `fsPromises.access()` to check for the accessibility of a file before calling `fsPromises.open()` is not recommended. Doing so introduces a race condition, since other processes may change the file's state between the two calls. Instead, user code should open/read/write the file directly and handle the error raised if the file is not accessible.

That refers to `open`, but it's just as applicable to things that do the `open` implicitly, like `readFile`.